# How to set custom image to facebook share using CURL

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am using this to share a content to facebook:

```
curl -X POST \
     -F "id=http://www.vtrack.cl/" \
     -F "scrape=true" \
     -F "picture=http://www.vtrack.cl/pub/media/social/gps303g_fb.png" \
     "https://graph.facebook.com"
```

I need to customize which image is shown in the sharing dialog, but it did not work. Can you help me?

Comment: "it didn´t work" is not a sufficient error/problem description. what about curl results? any specific message? why do you want to set a custom image? share images are not supposed to be dynamic.

Comment: why down voted? "it did not work" means "image was not set". I thought it was clear enough, or for people who knows about Facebook programming, at least.

Comment: I need to set a custom image because Facebook cuts edges of the image that is shown. I have a resized version of the image,so that Facebook dialog would show it complete

Comment: with "not sufficient", i mean that your question is missing debug information. debug the curl call.

Comment: check out my answer, i just tested your page and found out that there are no og tags at all

Answer (score 0):

You don´t have ANY OG tags on your website. With the `scrape=true` parameter, you can refresh the OG tags, but i am pretty sure you can´t just set any image. You need to add that image URL as `og:image` tag.

I am not sure if this is even documented correctly - it should work to refresh the tags though, i am doing the same with JavaScript. There´s definitely no picture parameter though, although i don´t even find the "scrape" parameter and that one definitely works: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/url

Comment: I cannot place og tags because this site is in developed in Magento Commerce, and for strange reasons the "property" attribute is removed from the meta tag when rendered.

Comment: then fix that problem, you can´t just "inject" OG tags. The Facebook scraper may visit the page again later and refresh them automatically, so even if it would be possible, it´s pointless.